# Практическое использование BinaryTree в c#

Tags: c#, ado.net, best-practice

Подскажите где на практике можно применить бинарное дерево? Какие-нибудь примеры использования этой структуры?
Заранее спасибо

Comment: Индексы в бд обычно представлены каким либо бинарным деревом  поиска, например красно-черным. А вообще, вы бы хотя бы [википедию](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE) почитали, там же есть применение.

Comment: В поиске, наверное, в основном. Может в балансировке какой-нибудь.